# Error after uploading laravel project from local to web server

Tags: mysql, laravel

I uploaded a laravel project from local to web server. After uploading I get following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1275] Server is running in --secure-auth mode, but 'root'@'127.0.0.1' has a password in the old format; please change the password to the new format (SQL: select * from `video_categories`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MySQL version 4.1, the way in which user passwords are stored was changed for greater security. By default, the server will still allow users with passwords stored in the old format to connect for backwards compatibility. However, if the server is running with the --secure-auth parameter or the secure-auth option specified in the [mysqld] section of it's option file, users that have a password stored in this old format will not be allowed to connect.

To allow the user to connect, you can either disable secure-auth mode by removing the option/parameter and restarting the server or reset the user's password with the new format. The problem with resetting the user's password is that if you do not know the existing password you will have to change it.

To reset the password, run the following command on the server in mysql:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('password');
```

Comment: I dont have access to the server.

Comment: The pw has been reset, but I have still the same problem.

Comment: How did you reset the password... you said you don't have the access to the server?

Comment: I asked the person who uploaded the project.